# Problem with Sending and Receiving Files with SPP over Bluetooth

Tags: java, file-upload, bluetooth

I am attempting to transfer files (MP3s about six megabytes in size) between two PCs using SPP over Bluetooth (in Java, with the BlueCove API).  I can get the file transfer working fine in one direction (for instance, one file from the client to the server), but when I attempt to send any data in the opposite direction during the same session (i.e., send a file from the server to the client), the program freezes and will not advance.

For example, if I simply:

```
StreamConnection conn;
OutputStream outputStream;

outputStream = conn.openOutputStream();

....

outputStream.write(data);  //Data here is an MP3 file converted to byte array

outputStream.flush();
```

The transfer works fine.  But if I try:

```
StreamConnection conn;
OutputStream outputStream;
InputStream inputStream;
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

outputStream = conn.openOutputStream();
inputStream = conn.openInputStream();

....

outputStream.write(data);
outputStream.flush();


int receiveData;
while ((receiveData = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
   out.write(receiveData);
}
```

Both the client and the server freeze, and will not advance.  I can see that the file transfer is actually happening at some point, because if I kill the client, the server will still write the file to the hard drive, with no issues.  I can try to respond with another file, or with just an integer, and it still will not work.

Anyone have any ideas what the problem is?  I know OBEX is commonly used for file transfers over Bluetooth, but it seemed overkill for what I needed to do.  Am I going to have to use OBEX for this functionality?

Comment: Can you post a summary of the client side code?

Comment: Wire dumps (using some sort of sniffer) would certainly help. You might want to use something like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to dump it and attach to this question

Answer (score 2):

It could be as simple as both programs stuck in blocking receive calls, waiting for the other end to say something...  try adding a ton of log statements so you can see what "state" each program is in (ie, so it gives you a running commentary such as "trying to recieve", "got xxx data", "trying to reply", etc), or set up debugging, wait until it gets stuck and then stop one of them and single step it.

Comment: It does appear that both programs are blocking on receive calls.  The write operation is non-blocking and writing to the output stream returns nothing to indicate the transfer is complete.  I have not found anyway to consistently wait until the transfer is done to start listening on the connection (outside of writing one byte at a time in a for-loop, or some other variation that's likely to take forever).  As soon as you call inputStream.read(), the output is evidently interrupted.

Comment: If you can't figure out how to put it into a non-blocking mode or query data availability (the docs are less than enthusiastic about the reliability of InputStream.available() but it might be better than issuing a read blindly), could you solve this by doing the reads from a different thread?

Answer (score 1):

you can certainly use SPP to transfer file between your applications (assuming you are sending and receiving at both ends using your application). From the code snippet it is difficult to tell what is wrong with your program.
I am guessing that you will have to close the stream as an indication to the other side that you are done with sending the data .. Note even though you write the whole file in one chunk, SPP / Bluetooth protocol layers might fragment it and the other end could receive in fragments, so you need to have some protocol to indicate transfer completion.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say without looking at the client side code, but my guess, if the two are running the same code (i.e. both writing first, and then reading), is that the `outputStream` needs to be closed before the reading occurs (otherwise, both will be waiting for the other to close their side in order to get out of the read loop, since `read()` only returns `-1` when the other side closes).

If the stream should not be closed, then the condition to stop reading cannot be to wait for `-1`. (so, either change it to transmit the file size first, or some other mechanism).

Answer (score 0):

Why did you decide to use ByteArrayOutputStream? Try following code:

```
    try {
        try {

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

            outputstream = conn.openOutputStream();
            inputStream = conn.openInputStream();

            while ((n = inputstream.read(buf, 0, 1024)) > -1)
                outputstream.write(buf, 0, n);                

        } finally {
            outputstream.close();
            inputstream.close();
            log.debug("Closed input streams!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    log.error(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And to convert the outputStream you could do something like this:

```
byte currentMP3Bytes[] = outputStream.toString().getBytes();
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(currentMP3Bytes);
```

Comment: The ByteArrayOutputStream was used because I didn't know the size of the file to be transmitted across the network before hand.  Given that the files are songs and could be very large (think a 20 minute long orchestral score) or relatively small, it seemed impractical to allocate a generically sized buffer.  That's evidently a fairly common way of doing that, from what I gather through the research I've done.